# binding dictionary in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

i have a dictonary

```
public class TAGs :INotifyPropertyChanged{
private Dictionary<string, string[]> _items = new Dictionary<string,string[]>();
 ...............
public string[] Keys
    {
        get { return Items.Keys.ToArray(); }
    }

}
```

i want to create 2 list, 1 list for the key and the other list contain the values of the selected keys, i tried this but it doesnt work

```
<ListBox x:Name="TagNameList" ItemsSource="{Binding Keys}"/>
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items[{Binding SelectedItem,ElementName=TagNameList}]}"/>
```

i contained them to a grid and their datacontext is an object of TAGs, the 1st listbox is working fine as its simple binding to a property but the 2nd list, isnt working
any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"{Binding Items[{Binding SelectedItem,ElementName=TagNameList}]}"` isn't valid xaml.  You can't do a binding inside a path since the path is constructed at compile time.

When encountering this myself I've simply ended up binding something else to the `SelectedItem` of one `ListBox` and then when that gets notified of a change, also fire a `NotifyPropertyChanged` on another property exposing `Items[selectedKey]` to which my second `ListBox` is bound.

xaml:

```
<ListBox x:Name="TagNameList" ItemsSource="{Binding Keys}" SelectedItem={Binding Selected}/>
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ValueFromKey}"/>
```

C#:

```
string _selected;
public string Selected
{
    get { return _selected; }
    set 
    { 
        _selected= value; 
        OnPropertyChanged("Selected");
        OnPropertyChanged("ValueFromKey");
    }
}

public string[] ValueFromKey
{
    get { return Items[Selected]; }
}
```

Comment: can u provide an example please? i cant do the second list binding

Comment: That should about do it.  Let me know if you need more.

Comment: thanks man :) you have no idea how much work around i have been trying till i gave up

Comment: No problem.  I tried 3-4 different solutions myself when I tried to do this the first time.